# Active Directory - can I force a re-resolve to use a different DC?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm not an AD expert, but have to try to fix a bug we have in our code... (seems to be an intermittent connectivity error).

In a bit of C# library code (used by an ASP.Net app), I am getting an AD Provider like so:

```
ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider provider =
    Membership.Providers[providerName] as ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider;
```

and my connection string(s) look like this:

```
 <add name="ASIAPAC" connectionString="LDAP://asiapac.ad.bigbank.com/DC=asiapac,DC=ad,DC=bigbank,DC=com" />
```

2 Questions in one really.

1. With the above, can anyone tell me if that means we are specifying a particular DC? [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819612/forms-authentication-against-active-directory-ldap-protocol) makes me think so, but my systems guys disagree and think that that just means the domain.
2. Once we have the connection strings correctly specifying only the domain, can I, on the fly in code, force the provider to re-resolve and use a different DC within the domain? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing serverless binding with the first component of the connection string. Specifying the FQDN of the domain on the left there isn't really necessary.

I don't know how the provider works. Ultimately it calls in to DC Locator (which you could invalidate the cache for), but when the provider needs to call through to DC Locator I don't know.

Comment: From my previous reading, I understand that using connectionString="LDAP://asiapac" would be serverless binding?

Comment: LDAP://dc=asia,dc=mycorp,dc=com would be serverless. LDAP://<anything>/dc=asia,dc=mycorp,dc=com would be not serverless for lack of a better term coming to mind